# What is Keep it alive?

Tags: wordpress, performance, gtmetrix

I've got a wordpress site, I'm trying to make it faster and better.
Using gtmetrix there is an error Enable Keep-Alive it's in 0 percent
how do I make it 100%?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples.

Answer (score 0):

GT-metrix says it all

https://gtmetrix.com/enable-keep-alive.html

Enabling Keep-Alive connections in Apache

Apache enables Keep-Alive connections by default, however you can explicitly turn them on by adding the following line to your httpd.conf file.

```
KeepAlive On
```

Having said that, if your site is running on a shared host, you probably won't have access to httpd.conf and will therefore have to live with whichever setting your hosting provider has chosen. Contrary to what some websites suggest, adding a Header set Connection keep-alive directive to your .htaccess file will not actually enable Keep-Alive connections, but it will send browsers misleading information about the server's capabilities.